# output escaping in alt text with xslt1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In my source XML, the less-than sign is represented as `&lt;`, but in the output (html, as alt-text) it is represented as the `<` sign, which causes problems in post-processing.

I'm using saxon655 with this command line:

```
java -cp saxon655/saxon.jar com.icl.saxon.StyleSheet test.xml test.xsl
```

This really doesn't make sense to me. Here are the details:

The DocBook XML:

```
<chapter xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
  <info><title>The Chapter</title></info>
    <para>
      <informalequation>
        <mediaobject>
          <imageobject>
            <imagedata fileref="images/g0589.png" />
          </imageobject>
          <textobject role="tex"><phrase>|z_ s-z_ t|&lt;r</phrase></textobject>
        </mediaobject>
      </informalequation>
    </para>
</chapter>
```

The XSLT. If you copy this, change the path the docbook stylesheets.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="/path/to/docbook/xsl-1.78.1/html/docbook.xsl" />

  <xsl:template match="d:mediaobject/d:imageobject/d:imagedata">
    <xsl:element name="img">
      <xsl:attribute name="alt">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../d:textobject[@role='tex']/d:phrase" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="@fileref" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the resulting HTML portion:

```
<div class="informalequation">
  <div class="mediaobject">
    <img alt="|z_ s-z_ t|<r" src="images/g0589.png"></div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is `java -jar saxon655/saxon.jar com.icl.saxonStyleSheet test.xml test.xsl` really the command line? I thought that the `-jar` option does not take a class and even if it did, the name of the class is `com.icl.saxon.StyleSheet`.

Comment: you're right--I wrote it instead of copying it. I'll edit the thing now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the W3C HTML validator says, for text/html the output is fine, I created a minimal HTML 4.01 document with the markup you have at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/html/test2015040301.html, it has the content

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>img alt attribute test</title>
</head>
  <body>

<div class="informalequation">
  <div class="mediaobject">
    <img alt="|z_ s-z_ t|<r" src="images/g0589.png"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the validator says (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.arcor.de%2Fmartin.honnen%2Fhtml%2Ftest2015040301.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) "This document was successfully checked as HTML 4.01 Strict!". So I think Saxon is creating correct HTML, I don't know how you post-process the result of the XSLT transformation but an HTML or SGML parser should do fine with it.

With an XML output (`method="xml"`) Saxon does escape the less than in the attribute value.

Comment: interesting. xsltproc leaves the entity as-is. And if I add `&amp;` to the `<phrase>` element, saxon leaves it alone, yet translates the `&lt;`. The postprocess is sending the alt text to a MathJax server to create SVG and MathML. I'll handle these issues on the app side.